# Help with Calculated Column Formula

Tags: list, calculated-column-formula

This is probably very simple, but I can't seem to get it working. I need to build a calculated column formula based on the below in my SharePoint list.

Calculated Column Name is called Status

The fields used in the formula are Form Status (single line of text column), Outcome (choice column) and Date of Outcome (date column)

The Status column should be as follows:

**In Progress** > Form Status = Draft

**Submitted** > Form Status = Submitted

**Referred** > Outcome = Agreed AND Date of Outcome is blank

**Closed** > Outcome = Agreed AND Date of Outcome is not blank OR Outcome = Rejected

Any help would be much appreciated!